# Telling Rails to look somewhere other than public/assets for assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to deploy an admin dashboard on top of a Rails API. Currently, it's Ingress service is setup at site.com/api/admin, and Rails is searching for the assets at site.com/assets, so it doesn't find them.

How can I tell Rails to look for the assets at site.com/api/assets/admin.css? I've tried using `config.assets.prefix = '/api/'`, but that seems to just change the directory the assets are precompiled to to `public/api/assets`, but in application.html.erb, the stylesheet link tag is still `public/assets/admin.css`, resulting in 404 errors for all assets.

Comment: are you sure not using API only version ?

Answer (score 1):

After days of troubleshooting, I tried setting `config.relative_url_root` to `'/api'`, and it's now finally working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the folder's path into the asset pipeline. You can do it by going to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and adding the following line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('my', 'folder', 'path')
```

Or, in this case:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'public', 'api', 'assets')
```